# How to invert the MQL query (for freebase)?

Tags: api, error-handling, reverse, freebase, mql

I am trying to list all the types for a particular id:

```
{
  "id": "/en/sony",
  "type": [{
    "name": "Topic",
    "id": null
  }]
}
```

This query giving me the following result:
http://tinyurl.com/lubavey

```
{
  "result": {
    "type": [
      {
        "id": "/common/topic",
        "name": "Topic"
      },
      {
        "id": "/base/audiobase/topic",
        "name": "Topic"
      },
      {
        "id": "/base/fblinux/topic",
        "name": "Topic"
      },
      {
        "id": "/base/digitalcameras/topic",
        "name": "Topic"
      },
      {
        "id": "/base/popstra/topic",
        "name": "Topic"
      },
      {
        "id": "/base/televisions/topic",
        "name": "Topic"
      },
      {
        "id": "/base/ps3games/topic",
        "name": "Topic"
      },
      {
        "id": "/base/filmcameras/topic",
        "name": "Topic"
      },
      {
        "id": "/m/04mny2g",
        "name": "Topic"
      }
    ],
    "id": "/en/sony"
  }
}
```

I want exactly the opposite result. I want all the types which do not have name as "Topic" with them.
How can I  achieve this? I tried to use `!` operator with property `name` which is suggested in reference guide of MQL, but it's giving me error:

> "Can't use unqualified property names with ! reversing".

What should I do to remove this error with `!` and to obtain opposite result of the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `!=`:

```
{
  "id": "/en/sony",
  "type": [{
    "name!=": "Topic",
    "id": null
  }]
}
```

> The != operator says that the constrained property can be anything but
>   the specified value. (It does require that the property be something,
>   however: it does not match object for which the property is null.)

Read more about `!=` operator here: http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/MQL_operators#The_.22but_not.22_Operator_.21.3D

Comment: Thanks Paul! It exactly does what I wanted. +1 for sharing the link for the operator uses.